# JOIN por LINQ em C#

Tags: c#, linq

Preciso fazer um join por LINQ em duas listas usando codigoLista.
A lista 1 deve existir na segunda lista (lista 2) e precisa ser retornada.
Como faço isso?
Obs.: Nunca fiz join via LINQ em c#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

você pode fazer da seguinte forma.:

**OUTER JOIN**

```
var set1 = new HashSet<Entity1>();
var set2 = new HashSet<Entity2>();

var query =
    from entity1 in set1
    join entity2 in set2 on entity1.Codigo equals entity2.Codigo
    select new {
        Entity1 = entity1,
        Entity2 = entity2
    };
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```
var set1 = new HashSet<Entity1>();
var set2 = new HashSet<Entity2>();

var query =
    from entity1 in set1
    join entity2 in set2 on entity1.Codigo equals entity2.Codigo into lSet
    from entity2 in lSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        Entity1 = entity1,
        Entity2 = entity2
    };
```

Lembrando que não é possível fazer um `Right Join`, no máximo você pode fazer um `Left Join` invertendo a ordem das coleções.

**RIGHT JOIN**

```
var set1 = new HashSet<Entity1>();
var set2 = new HashSet<Entity2>();

var query =
    from entity2 in set2
    join entity1 in set1 on entity2.Codigo equals entity1.Codigo into rSet
    from entity1 in rSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        Entity1 = entity1,
        Entity2 = entity2
    };
```

Também não é possível fazer o `Full Join` de maneira simples, você terá de fazer um `Left Join` e um `"Right Join"`, então unir ambos.

**FULL JOIN**

```
var set1 = new HashSet<Entity1>();
var set2 = new HashSet<Entity2>();

var lQuery =
    from entity1 in set1
    join entity2 in set2 on entity1.Codigo equals entity2.Codigo into lSet
    from entity2 in lSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        Entity1 = entity1,
        Entity2 = entity2
    };

var rQuery =
    from entity2 in set2
    join entity1 in set1 on entity2.Codigo equals entity1.Codigo into rSet
    from entity1 in rSet.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
        Entity1 = entity1,
        Entity2 = entity2
    };

var query = lQuery.Union(rQuery);
```

Comment: Isso ainda é muito difícil pra mim, mas preciso aprender urgente a construir o LEFT JOIN.

Comment: as duas listas são as seguintes: 'List<Familia> familiasFxa = Bo.ExecuteProcedureList<Familia>(connectionString, "STP_SEL_Familia");
            familiasFxa.Insert(0, new Familia() { CodFamilia = "0", DescricaoFamilia = "Selecione a Familia" });
            return familiasFxa;

            List<FamiliaArea> familiasAreaFxa = Bo.ExecuteProcedureList<FamiliaArea>(connectionString, "STP_SEL_FamiliaArea");' como ficaria? sendo que FamiliaArea deve estar em Familia

Comment: @MarianaDelfino tem como editar a sua pergunta e adicionar este código?

Comment: `List<Familia> familiasFxa = Bo.ExecuteProcedureList<Familia>(connectionString, "STP_SEL_Familia"); familiasFxa.Insert(0, new Familia() { CodFamilia = "0", DescricaoFamilia = "Selecione a Familia" }); return familiasFxa; List<FamiliaArea> familiasAreaFxa = Bo.ExecuteProcedureList<FamiliaArea>(connectionString, "STP_SEL_FamiliaArea");`

Comment: @TobyMosque Esse join é muito importante acho. Acontece o seguinte: Existe um grupo geral de familias de produtos. Os produtos terao seus preços alterados. Num primeiro momento, devem-se selecionar as familias. Vamos supor, eu selecionei apenas a familia
"Papelaria" e "Alimentos". No segundo momento, quando for aplicado o percentual de desconto deve-se aparecer somente as opçoes de "Papelaria" e "Alimentos" e no meu caso aparecem todas as familias, mesmo as que nao foram definidas. Acredito que um join por linq possa resolver o problema mas nao tenho ctz tb.

Comment: @MarianaDelfino a sua duvida já escapa ao escopo da pergunta, aconselho que faça uma nova pergunta, não esqueça de adicionar as classes `Familia` e `FamiliaArea` (não é possível responder a sua pergunta sem conhecer a estrutura de ambas), detalhe o seu problema, se possível informe o resultado esperado. e por fim, evite colocar código nos comentários, é difícil de ler, entender e copiar, se precisar adicionar alguma informação, edite à pergunta, deixe os comentários paras as duvidas.

Comment: @TobyMosque cheguei a uma solução tirando duvidas com a equipe de desenvolvimento. de qualquer forma seu codigo ajudou muito, obrigada!